# React tsx nested array print data in console but not in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, apache-superset, tsx

I have a column list in `keylist` array and all data in the `item` array.

In following code works well in the console. But in react it shows this error `An error occurred while rendering the visualization: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Invalid Date). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

```
   <div>
   {
    data.map((item) => {
     console.log("new row: ")
      return (
       <div className="row">
        {
          keylist.map(subitem => {
           return(
            // <p>{item[subitem]}</p>
            console.log(item[subitem])
           )
          })
         }
         </div>
        )
       })    
      }
     </div>
```

Comment: Put console log before the return statement.

Comment: and return a valid element from your return statement. That should work

Comment: @ahmed can you give me an example of a valid return element?

Comment: `return ( console )` works but I want to print that element. There is problem at `return ( <p>{item[subitem]}</p>)`

Comment: I have provided a solution in the answer.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. This is printing the data and also displaying on screen. Jope that helps

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-cherry-hvwr4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: problem is solved by `return <p> String(item[subitem]) </p>`. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution of your problem, Add return key after first map.

```
  {data.map(item => {
          return (
            <div className="row">
              {keylist.map(subitem => {
                return (
                  // <p>{item[subitem]}</p>
                  console.log(item[subitem])
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );

          console.log("new row: ");
        })}
```